# Strong params, nested attributes: Can't mass-assign

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 4.0.2 and can't get strong parameters to work with nested attributes.

```
# Model
has_one :availability
accepts_nested_attributes_for :availability

# Controller
def base_content_params
 params.require("base_content").permit(:enabled, :language, :title, :description,
      availability_attributes: [:duration, :slots])
end

# View
form_for [app, base_content] do |form|
  form.fields_for :availability do | a |
    a.select 'duration', duration_values
  end

  form.fields_for :availability do | a |
    a.select 'slots', [*(1..10)]
  end
```

But I keep getting:

`Can't mass-assign protected attributes for BaseContent: availability_attributes`

```
>> base_content_params
=> {"enabled"=>"false", "title"=>"test", "description"=>"", availability_attributes"=>{"duration"=>"30", "slots"=>"10"}}

# request parameters    
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"---", "base_content"=>{"enabled"=>"false", "language_id"=>"12938", "title"=>"test", "description"=>"", "content"=>"", "terms"=>"", "category"=>"product", "category_mode"=>"appy_booking", "responder_email"=>"", "price"=>"111.00", "price_per"=>"unit", "availability_attributes"=>{"start_at(5i)"=>"17:45:00", "id"=>"1", "duration"=>"30", "slots"=>"10"}, "reward_points"=>"100", "hash_tags"=>"", "lat"=>"", "lng"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save & Continue edit", "geocoder_lat"=>"0.0", "geocoder_lng"=>"0.0", "pac-input"=>"", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"backend/base_contents", "app_id"=>"1898", "id"=>"16108"}
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT

```
# BaseContent Model

class BaseContent < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :enabled, :price, :price_per, :app, :menu, 

# App Model
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :allow_search, :display_logo_badge, #... etc
```

Comment: Could you provide your complete view file ?

Comment: @Dusht: I've added the start of the form.

Comment: Strong params does not throw such an exception. This error looks like it's coming from `protected_attributes` gem. Do you have such a gem in your Gemfile?

Comment: @BroiSatse: I do yes.

Comment: @dan-klasson - Get rid of it and restart the application. `protected_attributes` are not needed in rails 4, the only reason to have them is to ease the transition to strong params. This gem requires you to add a list of accessible attributes in your model with `attr_accessible`.

Comment: @BroiSatse: This is a legacy app, there are loads of `attr_accessible` littered throughout the code base. I cannot use the `protected_attributes` in conjunction with `strong params`?

Comment: Are you using Rails 3 or 4?

Comment: @BroiSatse: `4.0.2`. I tried adding in `include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection` in my `Activity` model and removing all the `attr_accessible` from that model, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but it was too long.

From your comments, it's now clearer what the problem is. If you're using `Rails 4.0.2`, you have to switch to using `strong_params` in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @model = Model.new model_params
      @model.save
   end

   private

   def model_params
     params.require(:model).permit(:attribute1, :attribute2)
   end
end
```

I would **strongly** recommend you go through your models, remove any `attr_accessible` references, get rid of the `protected_attributes` gem and rebuild the functionality for strong params.

--

Another issue I can see is the way you're calling your form:

```
form_for [app, base_content] do |form|
```

Why are you nesting `base_content` (which should be an instance variable) under `app`? If anything, I'd expect something along the lines of...

```
form_for @base_content do |form|
```

Comment: It's a nested form that saves two models. We are using `decent exposure`, that's why they are not instance variables. There are about 40 models I would have to modify. Removing `attr_accessible` from the nested Availability model is not enough? Do I also need to remove it from App and BaseContent?

Comment: Without seeing your `BaseContent` and `App` models, I couldn't say